# Flurl exception not being caught

Tags: c#, flurl

I don't understand why but I'm receiving Flurl Exceptions and those are not being caught by the try/catch block. Any ideas on why that's happening?

Here's the code:

```
try
{
    var x = await Utils.Sales.GetUrl()
        .PostJsonAsync(new Sale
        {
            MerchantId = Constants.Sandbox.MerchantId
        })
        .ReceiveJson<Sale>();
    var b = x;
}
catch (FlurlHttpTimeoutException)
{
    //LogError("Timed out!"); //todo: 
}
catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
{
    var x = ex.Message;
    //todo: 
    //if (ex.Call.Response != null)
    //    LogError("Failed with response code " + call.Response.StatusCode);
    //else
    //    LogError("Totally failed before getting a response! " + ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var a = ex.Message;
}
```

Here's the output (the only reason why I know the exception is being thrown):

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is being caught in the library or the method you're calling?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz I'm sorry but I couldn't understand... Are you suggesting that I have another try/catch somewhere or that the exception is being handled by some other library?

Comment: @eestein It's possible that the library is throwing the exception, catching it, and handling it. The output logs is showing thrown exceptions (including those which have been caught)

Comment: @Rob I understand. But the library itself provides the Exception treatment option and on the creator's page he uses that same code as an example. With that in mind I think that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Anyone besides you working on this project? All I can think of is that someone may have [configured a global error handler](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/configuration/) that calls `call.ExceptionHandled = true`, which would prevent the exception from bubbling up to your code.

Comment: @ToddMenier hi Todd, only myself. The only thing I configure globally is the ModernHttpClient. I don't know why that's happening (the exception being handled) but I found out why the exception was thrown after moving my code to use restclient. It was the TLS version. The API used 1.2 but my project is running on .NET 4.5.2 and only 4.6+ has OOTB support. Is there a way to force that on flurl? I'd like to use it (I'm using it on 2 other projects) but I can't upgrade the 4.5.2 project right now. If you can try to take a look at that exception being caught. Lemme know if you need more code/info!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this page will help https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/jj619227.aspx
Sorry don't have a english version, you can try google translate it.
It's someting wrong with you catch exception type or await code.
Try this way catch your exception:
```

```
try
{
    await t1;
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    var innerEx = ex.InnerExceptions[0];
    if (innerEx is NotSupportedException)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (innerEx is NotImplementedException)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

```

Comment: I don't understand what's written there but I understand the code. I think it's the same thing I'm doing, ain't it?

Comment: same code like yours it's the wrong catch example, below is the right way catch exception, and show some other way handle exception of await in this article. Also some explain of thoese design. I only do a quick read get some summary.